# Reuse same variable name twice within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, design-principles

```
for i in rates:
    if input_currency == currency:
        if output_currency in rates[currency]:
            pass 
        else:
            for i in rates:
```

Is it generally a bad thing to use the same variable `i` again within a for loop? Even if I loop through the same data structure again? PyCharm just tells me it's been used already, but it still works.

Comment: It's not a problem as long as you use it only as a counter in the `for` statements

Comment: `i` should only be used to note an index, if at all, give yourself a real variable name, having said that, why do you need to iterate over the same object?

Comment: Don't do this. Use `j` and then `k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong. But it's dangerous if you don't know what you are doing. For example, you might have problems if you want to use `i` inside the outer loop:

```
rates = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in rates:
    for i in rates:
        pass
    print(i) # This always prints 5
```

This may confuse you if you're not familiar with Python. In C, for example, a variable defined inside the inner loop is different from the one that is defined in the outer loop (i.e., you can reuse the same name for different variables).

Comment: Should also point out that this works as you would expect if you move the print statement above the inner loop